# Java Array Basics

Tags: java

```
package basic;

class TestIt {

    static void doIt(int[] z) {
        z = null;
    }
}

class Arraydemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] myArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

        TestIt.doIt(myArray);

        for (int j = 0; j < myArray.length; j++)
            System.out.print(myArray[j] + " ");
    }

}
```

can any1 please explain why the output for code is 1,2,3,4,5. ....................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: It looks like homework. What did you try?

Comment: yes we can, `z=null` is only updating local variable in doIt method

Comment: read this question [is java pass-by-reference or pass-by-value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Answer (score 2):

Java is `pass by value`, which means that when you assign `z = null` it does not change `myArray`.

To set `myArray` to `null` you have to set it explicitely in `main`:

```
class Arraydemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] myArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

        myArray = null;                

}
```

Comment: alright thats fine..

Answer (score 2):

In Java object references are passed by value. When you do this

```
static void doIt(int[] z) {
    z = null;
}
```

you set the value of object reference `z` to `null`. At this point, your `doIt` method can no longer reference `myArray` local variable from the `main` method, but the array stays unchanged, along with the `myArray` variable, which is referring to it.

Answer (score 1):

Because in java *references to objects are passed by value*.
So `TestIt.doIt(myArray);` will only change the value of `myArray` to `null` in the `doIt()` method.

If you want the value to be changed in the *calling* method as well, use :

`myArray = TestIt.doIt(myArray);`